# How to create a webview with phonegap?

Tags: android, cordova

I just installed phonegap and am new to it.I imported the example under android folder and ran it, and it seems to show the underlying files properly. However, How do I go about importing my html/js files.I tried to look up online, but no luck so far. How do I create a project for webview in phonegap and at the same time import my js/html files.do I also have to code in android for the same or phone gap does everything for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put your html, js and css files in the assets folder.

In the main activity, your refer to them as follows:

```
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
```

As per [PhoneGap Documentation - Getting Started with Android](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html)

**EDIT**

Regarding formating and making it fit on the screen will depend on the way you treat your html, css and js files. For example, here is an html file that fits on the screen independently on the orientation and screen size:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
    Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
    or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
    distributed with this work for additional information
    regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
    to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
    "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
    with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
    software distributed under the License is distributed on an
    "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
     KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
    specific language governing permissions and limitations
    under the License.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
            <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
                <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

What I've done was to summarize the original cordova's html, that works perfectly on the application.

More about formmating, please refer to web design questions instead of PhoneGap, once the app is up and running.

Comment: are you talking with respect to the example there, do i modify that or there is some __activity__ and __package_ thingy, which one do i use /modify?

Comment: nvm, will try out the documentation and figure out :) , if i have more questions, i'll get back to you, if not, you get a +25 :D

Comment: Ok! This tutorial is pretty complete and also straightforward, I believe this is from a big help to beginners. Any other doubt you may have please feel free to ask. This tutorial refers to and old version of PhoneGap and you may want to download a newer one, the tutorial will still fit your needs.

Comment: i am able to load my app, however , it shows in the minimized form (doesnt take up the entire screen) and on top theres no sound :\, how do i fix that?